# Facebookのエラーハンドリング

Tags: android, facebook-api

現在AndroidとFacebookを連携したアプリを作成しているのですが、Androidがインターネットに繋がっていない状態でアプリからFacebookにログインしようとすると、ログインのViewが一瞬現れてすぐに消えてしまいます。なのでその際のエラーコードなどを知りたいのですが、色々と調べてみてもどうすればいいか分かりません。どこにどういうメソッドを追加すればFacebookでのエラーを検知することができるでしょうか？下記のコードがFacebookの認証 & 投稿のコードになります。すみませんが、宜しくお願いします。

```
public class PostFacebook {
    private static Activity mActivity;
    private static Session mSession;
    private boolean mLoopStopFlag;

    public PostFacebook(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            mLoopStopFlag = false;
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            if (mSession.getState() != SessionState.CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED) {
                if (!mLoopStopFlag) {
                    initSession();
                    mSession.openForPublish(new Session.OpenRequest(mActivity).setCallback(callback).setPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions")));
                    mLoopStopFlag = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    private void initSession() {
        mSession = new Session(mActivity);
        Session.setActiveSession(mSession);
    }

    public void shareFacebook() {
        if (mSession != null) {
            if (mSession.getState() == SessionState.CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED) {
                initSession();
                mSession.openForPublish(new Session.OpenRequest(mActivity).setCallback(callback).setPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions")));
            }
        } else {
            initSession();
            mSession.openForPublish(new Session.OpenRequest(mActivity).setCallback(callback).setPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions")));
        }
        post();
    }

    public static void post() {
        Bitmap image = FacebookContents.getInstance().getmImage();
        if (mSession.isOpened()) {
            Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(mSession, image, new
                    Request.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            if (response.getError() == null) {
                                Toast.makeText(mActivity, "メッセージを投稿しました。", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            } else {
                                if (mSession.getState() == SessionState.OPENED) { Toast.makeText(mActivity, "失敗", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
                            }
                        }
                    });
            Bundle params = request.getParameters();
            {
                params.putString("message", FacebookContents.getInstance().getmMessage());
            }
            request.executeAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 本題とはずれるのですが、ActivityのインスタンスをstaticフィールドにセットするのはNGですね

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。了解しました。ちなみにどうしてNGなのでしょうか？

Comment: 画面回転や、ホームボタンによる中断などで、Activityインスタンスはシステムによって破棄されます。しかし、static変数で保持してしまうと正しく解放されないのでメモリリークの原因になる上、破棄されたインスタンスにアクセスしてしまう　といった問題が起きます。

Comment: Activiyのインスタンスをstaticにしてしまうと予期せぬエラーの元になるのですね。。。大変参考になります。ご指摘ありがとうございます。